# Не подключаются доп поля carbon fields у шаблона страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Carbon Fields подключается с помощью этой функции в functions.php

```
// Доп поля

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'crb_load');
function crb_load()
{
  require_once('includes/carbon-fields/vendor/autoload.php');
  \Carbon_Fields\Carbon_Fields::boot();
}

add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields', 'register_carbon_fields');
function register_carbon_fields()
{
  require_once('includes/carbon-fields-options/theme-options.php');
  require_once('includes/carbon-fields-options/post-meta.php');
}
```

Код файла post-meta:

```
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  exit;
}

use Carbon_Fields\Container;
use Carbon_Fields\Field;

Container::make('post_meta', 'Дополнительные поля')
->where('post_type', '=', 'page')
->where('post_template', '=', 'page-home.php')
->add_tab('Главная секция', [
  Field::make('text', 'main_title', 'Заголовок (h1)'),
]);
```

Файл page-home.php находится в корне темы.
Проблема в том, что доп поля не подключаются у шаблона страницы (комментарий в шаблоне есть:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Главная
*/
?>
```

)

Если убрать проверку на шаблон, доп поля подключаются

Comment: `Файл page-home.php находится в корни темы` ... `->where('post_template', '=', 'templates/page-home.php')` -- это же не корень темы, если что `templates/page-home.php`

Comment: Извините, не поправил код, пробовал и так и так, отредактировал теперь

Answer (score 0):

Переустановил плагин, все заработало